# Multiple assignation with list comprehension

Tags: python, python-2.7, list-comprehension

I am trying to know if I can assign multiple lists with one single list comprehension. I somehow can't get my mind around the syntax.

So, instead of doing...

```
xs = [item.km for item in data]
ys = [item.price for item in data]
```

I'd like to do...

```
xs, ys = [km, price for km, price in data]
# or...
xs, ys = [item.km, item.price for item in data]
```

But this throws me a syntax error, and I can't seem to find the error.

Even if it seemed obvious, the data is as follow...

```
for elem in data:
    print elem
# outputs (this is a namedtuple) :
# mileage(km=22899.0, price=7990.0)
# mileage(km=48235.0, price=6900.0)
# mileage(km=54000.0, price=7990.0)
# mileage(km=60949.0, price=7490.0)
...
```

Comment: Please show the actual error, I doubt it is a syntax error.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If I understand your structure correctly, you need `zip()` with the star-argument to transpose your data:

```
xs, ys = zip(*[(km, price) for km, price in data])
```

Comment: This seems like the fairest answer at the moment. I'll check when I get back behind a computer

Comment: It does process the structure, but it converts the entirety of `data` several times (once into a list of tuples, then into a tuple of tuples, then into two iterators).

Comment: @YannVernier your alternative, initialising and appending/filling 2 lists in a loop, also has some overhead, I would need to time them to see which is quickest, but I find the approach here neater at least

Comment: I agree. Yours is far more direct and only for large sequences will the variant I wrote actually work better (any toy case will just fit in cache and render the comparison moot).  Most likely this type of translation belongs in the load phase, like creating a pandas dataframe.

Comment: I validate your answer because you provided the one-liner I asked for, but I'll settle for using a simple `for` loop instead then. :)

Answer (score 4):

A single list comprehension produces a single list. You've tried to assign a list of the structure `[(a,b), (a,b), (a,b)]` to two variables using multiple assignment, and this doesn't work because the number of entries doesn't match. You could instead produce lists of the pair components:

```
kms = [item.km for item in data]
prices = [item.price for item in data]
```

But this does process the list `data` twice. If it's really important to avoid this, we could build the two lists in parallel, but that still isn't a single comprehension:

```
kms, prices = [], []
for item in data:
    kms.append(item.km)
    prices.append(item.price)
```

You could achieve a lower load on the memory manager by preallocating the lists:

```
kms, prices = [None]*len(data), [None]*len(data)
for i,item in enumerate(data):
    kms[i]=item.km
    prices[i]=item.price
```

But most likely you'd be better off processing the data in a joint manner using something like numpy or pandas.

It's possible to use a fold to produce two lists with input from one comprehension, but it's both complex and inefficient in common Python implementations.

Comment: This is a great answer.

Comment: I'll settle for the `for` loop. :) but I was originally as how you would do this multiple assignment using one-liner.

Answer (score 1):

Simple answer is, like others have pointed already: **a list comprehension produces a single list**.

You could, however, as @Chris_Rands suggested, transpose your data using `zip`. I would tweak it and use a generator to make it a little faster.

```py
xs, ys = zip(*((item.km, item.price) for item in data))
```

The problem is that the above will iterate multiple times over the data set in order to produce what you expect. Using a plain `for` iteration will perform far better, as [Yann's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48461617/307511) states (that answer has an even better alternative):

```py
xs, ys = [], []
for item in data:
    xs.append(item.km)
    ys.append(item.price)
```

Sometimes we need to sacrifice some things in favour of performance. And in this case:

- `zip` is an great tool, but it isn't exactly meant for that. That snippet isn't easily readable for people unaware of the use case, and is also slow (O(2*n^2) or *maybe* O(n^2) with a generator, I haven't tested).
- Using a plain `for` will make your code really faster (O(n)), which may really matter depending on the size of `data`.

Comment: Well. Originally, I was curious if I could do a one-liner for multiple lists assignation with O(n) time. Now that I realize it might not be possible, I'll settle for a `for` loop. :)